# Combining multiple int variables into one int variable

Tags: c++, integer, combinations

I have three variables each with a single digit in them and I'm trying to combine them into one variable. For example:

```
int1 = 5 int2 = 3 int3 = 8
```

so the outcome would be number = 538

I've tried number = int1, int2, int3 but no success.

Comment: What language?  Please add some additional details to this question.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited it :)

Comment: In all seriousness, please read more about programming fundamentals before you take your exam.

Comment: Also brush up on your fundamental math skills.  Your issue is resolved by referencing the definition of base 10.

Answer (score 5):

```
int number = 100 * int1 + 10 * int2 + int3;
```